# When using boto3 ssm, the base working directory and conda environments are not the same as when I connect via EC2 instance connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to use the boto3 send_command function, and I have now gotten it to work but I noticed that the base working directory and some of my conda settings are not the same as when I connect via the EC2 instance connect command line interface.

When I use the "who" command in either, they will tell me that I am the same user. But these settings are still different.

Is there any way that I can have my environment be exactly the same via SSM as in the EC2 instance connect CLI?

update: I found out that when I use "whoami" instead of who, they will return different users ("ubuntu" and "root" respectively)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it:

I found out that even though it listed me as the same user with the "who" command, if I used "whoami" instead I noticed that my ssh client was in the user "root" instead of ubuntu.

So while on the EC2 instance connect command line I swapped over to the root user using "sudo su root", and set up the environments correctly over there.

Now my python script runs when it's called via SSM

Answer (score 0):

You can run command as a differnet user using your command as:

```py
f"runuser -l ubuntu -c '{cmd}'"
```

Optionally you can also set a working directory for ssm session:

```py
    'Parameters': {
        'commands': commands,
        'workingDirectory': ['/home/user'],
    }
```